# An unknown error occurred all the time

Tags: error-message, error

When creating, editing or deleting anything in CP the notification with "An unknown error occurred" is appended at the top.

I check the console and I get a 500 on these:

```
/index.php/admin/actions/tasks/runPendingTasks
/index.php/admin/actions/tasks/getRunningTaskInfo
```

Nothing is in the logs that I can see.

Answer (score 4):

I too just had this problem - upon any action in the control panel flashed "An unknown error occurred".

What I found in my craft web.log was: 
"ErrorException: ignore_user_abort() has been disabled for security reasons in"

Apparently in my server setup via Runcloud there are various advanced boilerplate Disable_Functions. I removed "ignore_user_abort". Problem solved.

Now the question is what does ignore_user_abort actually do...

Craft 3
PHP 7.2

Comment: Thank you! `ignore_user_abort()` is disabled by default on runcloud (php 7.2) and was causing all kinds of issues. @BradBell — may want to consider adding this to the server check in the control panel along with `proc_open()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

*Something* should be in the logs.  If it's happening on every page in the control panel, then most likely it's cURL related.

Clear your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files, reproduce the issue, then search the log file for `[error]` and that should have the underlying error message in it.

If nothing is there, then the 500 error is being generated by your web server and it should be in your web server's error logs.