# An unknown error occurred - no log entry

Tags: entries, craft2

After copying files from a web server to my local devbox I am unable to open any 'Entries'. I keep getting two of the following error: "An unknown error occured."

[image: There are always two errors]

<strike>The assets section does open and I am able to see the various loaded assets.</strike>. This also does not display, same error pop-up.

The strangest part is there are no logs to speak of... I tried clearing all the logs just in case, but they're still empty.

I'm using Laragon with PHP 7.2.11 Apache 2.4.35 and two different sites give me the same error.

EDIT: I have tried `ignore_user_abort = On` in my php.ini file as per a [similar issue](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/28364/9627)

EDIT: The only php error is recurring on every page load, but I thought it was a compatibility thing:

```
[24-Apr-2019 08:08:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant auto - assumed 'auto' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in D:\laragon\www\cannon-kitchens\craft\config\general.php on line 13
```

EDIT: I am now seeing some logs, but this appears to be normal operation:

```
2019-04-24 10:13:58
Level   profile
Category    system.db.CDbCommand.query
Message     end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`structureId` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`fieldLayoutId` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`handle` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`hasUrls` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`template` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`dateCreated` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`dateUpdated` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`uid` AS `t0_c9`, `structure`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `structure`.`maxLevels` AS `t1_c1`, `structure`.`dateCreated` AS `t1_c2`, `structure`.`dateUpdated` AS `t1_c3`, `structure`.`uid` AS `t1_c4` FROM `craft_categorygroups` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `craft_structures` `structure` ON (`t`.`structureId`=`structure`.`id`) ORDER BY name)
2019-04-24 10:13:58
Level   profile
Category    system.db.CDbCommand.query
Message     begin:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`structureId` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`fieldLayoutId` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`handle` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`hasUrls` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`template` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`dateCreated` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`dateUpdated` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`uid` AS `t0_c9`, `structure`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `structure`.`maxLevels` AS `t1_c1`, `structure`.`dateCreated` AS `t1_c2`, `structure`.`dateUpdated` AS `t1_c3`, `structure`.`uid` AS `t1_c4` FROM `craft_categorygroups` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `craft_structures` `structure` ON (`t`.`structureId`=`structure`.`id`) ORDER BY name)
2019-04-24 10:13:58
Level   trace
Category    system.db.CDbCommand
Message     Querying SQL: SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`structureId` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`fieldLayoutId` AS `t0_c2`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`handle` AS `t0_c4`, `t`.`hasUrls` AS `t0_c5`, `t`.`template` AS `t0_c6`, `t`.`dateCreated` AS `t0_c7`, `t`.`dateUpdated` AS `t0_c8`, `t`.`uid` AS `t0_c9`, `structure`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `structure`.`maxLevels` AS `t1_c1`, `structure`.`dateCreated` AS `t1_c2`, `structure`.`dateUpdated` AS `t1_c3`, `structure`.`uid` AS `t1_c4` FROM `craft_categorygroups` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `craft_structures` `structure` ON (`t`.`structureId`=`structure`.`id`) ORDER BY name
2019-04-24 10:13:58
Level   profile
Category    system.db.CDbCommand.query
Message     end:system.db.CDbCommand.query(SHOW CREATE TABLE `craft_structures`)
```

Comment: Can you produce normal error logs for php? What is the laragon path to php errors? Any errors in there or apache? Sounds like a 500 error/pathway problem to me

Comment: Check your browser's console's network tab and see if any the requests are coming back with a non-200 response... if so, what are they?

Comment: Thanks - The only non-200 code was a 404 for a favicon.ico but I didn't think that would make a difference? PHP error attached, but is it related?

Comment: I don't know if it will solve your problem, but somewhere in `config\general.php`, you have a setting set to `auto`, when it should be `'auto'` (with the quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your Cache manually going into the Storage folder. It happens when you add new entries and the code is not written properly or any other issue may reflect this error. So the best thing to clear the storage part manually.

To do this; Delete the entire folder `\craft\storage\runtime`

Comment: to be clear delete `\craft\storage\runtime\cache` or more than that? I have tried that, and the cache folder recreates, but the errors persist.

Comment: Yeah delete the runtime manually.